# How do I design a database to maintain history of inventory

Tags: database, algorithm, sqlite, database-design

I need help with designing database for following data.

Time1 : x,y,z

Time2 : x,x,y,z

Time3 : x,y,W

I need to store the above in database. How should I design my table. the list of inventory(x,y,z..) can be in hundreds. mostly I will be using this to get quick history change between 2 time stamps. and inserting new inventory into table periodically. Any suggestions on approach?

FYI: I am doing this in sqlite3
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Prof. Richard Snodgrass has written and kindly provided for free a fine book on this topic.

https://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/tdbbook.pdf